# Разумно ли заменить "превращение" на "коловращение" (см. контекст)?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика

> Сцена МХАТа уже тогда, в конце 80-х, была уникальна; на ней три круга,
>   которые могли двигаться одновременно и в одну сторону, и навстречу
>   друг другу. Говорят, эта сцена чуть ли не летать могла, пока какие-то
>   ценные детальки для этих *превращений (коловращений?)* не были скручены
>   злоумышленниками: уж больно подходили они для первых
>   видеомагнитофонов.

Все ли нарисованные мною знаки на своих местах?

Может, "уж больно подходили они для первых видеомагнитофонов" в скобочки заключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Сцена МХАТа уже тогда, в конце 80-х, была уникальна; на ней **три** круга, которые могли двигаться одновременно и в одну сторону, и навстречу друг другу **[** в **одну сторону** и **навстречу** - это два движения **в одной плоскости;  а вверх-вниз - третье- где? есть ли оно? В тексте - нет ]**. Говорят, эта сцена чуть ли не летать могла, пока какие-то ценные детальки для этих превращений (коловращений?) не были скручены злоумышленниками: уж больно подходили они для первых видеомагнитофонов.*

Как  *"советский технарь"* вижу так:

*Сцена МХАТа уже тогда, в конце 80-х, была уникальна - у нее было (**или были?**) **три** круга, которые могли двигаться **одновременно**: и в **одну** сторону, и **навстречу** друг другу, и **вверх-вниз**. Говорят, эта сцена чуть ли не **летать** могла, пока какие-то ценные детальки для этих- **особых** - превращений не были скручены злоумышленниками. Уж больно подходили они для первых видеомагнитофонов!*

Считаю, что лучше оставить *"превращение"*, потому что ***"коловращение"*** не все,  к великому сожалению, поймут так, каков есть смысл этого слова  в действительности.

P.S. Засомневалась: **было** три круга или **были** три круга?

Comment: Римма, спасибо! *БылО три круга.* В авторском тексте надо максимально сохранять "автора". Забавно про *вверх-вниз*; Вы не допускаете, что круги могли быть разного диаметра? Приписывать при редактуре мы ничего не можем, только спросить. Но терминологию приходится принимать на веру - иначе автор окосеет (офонареет) от нашей любознательности. )))

Comment: Сценических кругов может быть сколько угодно и разного диаметра. Но! - если они  все находятся в одной горизонтальной плоскости, - о "летабельности" не может быть и речи. Необходим механизм передвижения вверх-вниз. Люди искусства.. - они так ненаблюдательны к тому, что их напрямую не касается.

Comment: Мой "человек искусства" описывает свой сценический опыт. А летающая сцена - очевидная гипербола.

Comment: Да, занесло маленько. "Вверх-вниз" - это я перестаралась. Но, мне кажется, всё-таки было бы полезно оставить "особых превращений". И восклицательный знак в самом конце... P.S. Умеете Вы поставить на место... С уважением